# SDL Web8 Workflow failing with error String cannot be of zero length

Tags: web8, workflow, sdl-tridion

Workflow is failing with below error,can you please help me

System.ArgumentException: String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue at System.String.ReplaceInternal(String oldValue, String newValue) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at Abbott.Workflow.ProductWorkflow.MasterWorkflow.PublishToStaging.Execute() at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Workflow.ExternalActivity.ExecuteInternal(String activityInstanceId, String processInstanceXml, Action action) at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Workflow.ExternalActivity.Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.IExternalActivity.Execute(String activityInstanceId, String processInstanceXml) at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.ExternalActivityExecutor.ExecuteScript(String script, String currentActivityInstanceId, String processInstanceXml) at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowAgentEngine.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__1() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowAgentEngine.ProcessActivity(TcmUri activityInstanceId, Boolean isExpirationExecution)

Comment: Can you provide more context as to when your code is running - what is the intention; what's the pre-condition to this step? Just pasting code like this doesn't help anyone to help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs in implementation code: `Abbott.Workflow.ProductWorkflow.MasterWorkflow.PublishToStaging.Execute`

Comment: I found the issue by adding logs in the above method.The error is due to missing entries from configuration file, once updated correct configuration labels issue resolved,